# Is there a way to make Unix diff -r compare only differences in filenames, but not check if any single file actually differs?

Tags: unix, diff

I need to compare two large directories with a lot of files in them. I tried using:

```
diff -r Directory1 Directory2
```

but the process is really slow due to the amount of files and their huge size.

So I thought about making the process faster by just comparing the content of the folders and not the actual content of the files.
Is there a way to make diff recursively check only if every subdirectory of Directory1 and Directory2 match in name and file content, but not check if every single file in Directory1 actually matches every single file in Directory2?

For example, let's say I have Directory1/SubDirectory1 and Directory2/Subdirectory1.
I want to check only if Directory1/SubDirectory1.1 and Directory2/Subdirectory2.1 have the same number of files with the same filenames (let's say, file1, file2, ... fileN), but I don't care about matching every file1, file2 ... fileN of Directory1/SubDirectory1.1 to every file1, file2 ... fileN of SubDirectory2.1 to see if their content is actually the same.
Is there a way of doing this?

Edit:

I tried using:

```
diff <(path1) <(path2)
```

but unfortunately, diff outputs the full path for each file. The output I get is thus:

```
< /Volume1/.../.../Directory1/SubDirectory1.1/file1
< /Volume1/.../.../Directory1/SubDirectory1.1/file2
  ...
> /Volume2/.../.../Directory2/SubDirectory2.1/file1
> /Volume2/.../.../Directory2/SubDirectory2.1/file2
  ...
```

Here every single filename clearly differs, because the full paths differ.
Is there a way to force find to output paths only starting from the directory you give as argument? For example:

```
find -(some option I'm not aware of) /Volume1/.../.../Directory1
```

outputs:

```
/Directory1/SubDirectory1.1/file1
/Directory1/SubDirectory1.1/file2
...
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way:

```
cd /.../Directory1
find . | sort >/tmp/dir1.lst
cd /.../Directory2
find . | sort >/tmp/dir2.lst
diff /tmp/dir1.lst /tmp/dir2.lst
```

It will fail if your filenames contain newlines, but in many cases that isn't a concern.

If scripting this, make sure to use auto-generated temp file names, e.g. with `mktemp(1)`, to avoid symlink attacks and other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Nate Eldredge, thank you for your answer!
However, I was able to solve my problem creating a script named `fast_diff.sh`, with just a line of code, as follows:

```
diff <(find "$1" | sed "s|$1\/||g" | sort) <(find "$2" | sed "s|$2\/||g" | sort)
```

The script takes two arguments, let's say path1 and path2:

```
./fast_diff.sh /Volume1/.../.../Directory1 /Volume2/.../.../Directory2
```

Now the variable $1 is equal to "/Volume1/.../.../Directory1" and the variable $2 is equal to "/Volume2/.../.../Directory2".
The command `find` gives as output something like:

```
/Volume1/.../.../Directory1/SubDirectory1.1/file1
/Volume1/.../.../Directory1/SubDirectory1.1/file2
...
```

Now I pipe this output to sed, using:

```
sed "s|$1||g"
```

which replaces every occurrence of "/Volume1/.../.../Directory1" with nothing. I used `|` as a separator instead of `/` because there are many occurrences of `/` in the directory path.
Employing the previous line of code, though, lists all subdirectories and files starting with a slash:

```
/SubDirectory1.1/file1
/SubDirectory1.1/file2
...
```

To remove the slash, I added `\/`:

```
sed "s|$1\/||g"
```